# Multiple distinct columns (Pig)

Tags: apache-pig

I have a list of flights, with the following attributes:

- day: day they were flown
- flight_number: their flight number
- origin_airport: origin city airport
- dest_airport: destination city airport
- carrier_code: the airline carrier's code (eg. delta: DL)

I am trying to find the number of flights operated by each carrier. In doing so, for every day, I need to find distinct flight_number, origin_airport, dest_airport and carrier_code since one of the conditions is that "An airplane may be scheduled to fly from A to B and then from B to C with the same flight number on the same day. However, we consider these two journeys as two separate flights."

This is what I have that is not running:

```
 desiredattributes = FOREACH jnd GENERATE day, flight_number, origin_airport_id, dest_airport_id, carrier_code;

 distinctflights = FOREACH (GROUP desiredattributes BY day) 
 {
     a = carriers.(carrier_code, flight_number, origin_airport_id, dest_airport_id);
     b = DISTINCT a;
 };
 DUMP distinctflights;
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated! I am new to pig

Comment: I meant desiredattributes.(...);

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should list the fields from desiredattributes.

```
desiredattributes = FOREACH jnd GENERATE day, flight_number, origin_airport_id, dest_airport_id, carrier_code;
dayflights = GROUP desiredattributes BY day;
alldayflights = FOREACH dayflights GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as day,desiredattributes.flight_number,desiredattributes.origin_airport_id,desiredattributes.dest_airport_id, desiredattributes.carrier_code;
distinctflights = DISTINCT alldayflights;
DUMP distinctflights;
```